# Multiple definitions when using #ifdef

Tags: c++, definition, include-guards

I am having a problem when compiling: `Multiple definitions of "myFunction()"`
I will greatly simplify the problem here. Basically, I have 3 files: "main", "header", and "myLibrary".

- main.cpp

```
    #include "header.hpp"

    int main() {  }
```

- header.hpp

```
    #ifndef HEADER_HPP
    #define HEADER_HPP

    #include "myLibrary.hpp"

    // ...

    #endif
```

- header.cpp

```
    #include "header.hpp"

    // ...
```

- myLibrary.hpp

```
    #ifndef LIB_HPP
    #define LIB_HPP

    #if defined(__unix__)
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    std::string myFunction() { return std::string(); }
    #endif

    #endif
```

- myLibrary.cpp

```
    #include "myLibrary.hpp"

    //...
```

So, why does the compiler say that I have  `Multiple definitions of "myFunction()"`?

One clue I found: When I take header.cpp and erase the line that says `#include "header.hpp"`, the program compiles without complaining. On the other hand, if I erase `myFunction` (from myLibrary.hpp) instead, the program also compiles without complains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining the body of the function inside the header file.  So every translation unit that you include that header in (in this case, `main.cpp` and `header.cpp`) will end up with its own copy of that function body.  And when you try to link those multiple units together, you get the "duplicate definition" error.

The function needs to be *declared* in the hpp file, and *defined* in the cpp file:

myLibrary.hpp

```
#ifndef LIB_HPP
#define LIB_HPP

#if defined(__unix__)
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string>
std::string myFunction();
#endif

#endif
```

myLibrary.cpp

```
#include "myLibrary.hpp"

#if defined(__unix__)
std::string myFunction()
{
    return std::string();
}
#endif

//...
```

Comment: Isn't this just restating my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Include guards only prevent the same header from being included twice within the same *translation unit*, which in practice is usually a single `.cpp` file. For example, it prevents errors when doing this:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
}
```

But, more generally, it means that it doesn't matter if you've include a header that has already been included as a dependency of another header.

However, if you have *two* .cpp files include the same header, and that header contains the definition of a function (such as your `myLibrary.hpp`) then each .cpp file will have its own definition (the include guard won't help because the header is being included in two separate translation units / .cpp files).

The simplest thing to do is to declare the function in the header, which tells every file that includes your header that the function exists *somewhere*, and then define it in the .cpp file so that it is only defined once.

Answer (score 1):

You should to *define* functions in the .cpp files, not in the header files. You *declare* them in the header files. What you're doing is defining it in the header file, so when it gets included into multiple files, the function is getting duplicated. Cross-file duplicate symbols will throw an error, unless they're `static`.

myLibrary.cpp:

```
#include "myLibrary.hpp"
#ifdef(__unix__)
std::string myFunction() { return std::string(); }
#endif
```

myLibrary.hpp:

```
#ifndef LIB_HPP
#define LIB_HPP

#if defined(__unix__)
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string>
std::string myFunction();
#endif

#endif
```